# Google - 'Restricted scope verification' policy verification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

I would like to clarify couple point from the Google's 'Google API Services User Data Policy'.

Paragraph in Additional Requirements for Specific API Scopes:

1. Does this point means that data e.g. derived from the raw data can be used e.g. to show features that are clearly displaying that data, and are user-facing?

> Limited Use: Your use of data obtained via the product's specified
> scopes must comply with the below requirements. These requirements
> apply to the raw data obtained from the scopes and data aggregated,
> anonymized, or derived from them.
>
> Limit your use of data to providing or improving user-facing features
> that are prominent in the requesting application's user interface;

2. Second point I would like to clarify is wheter the transfer refers to saving data in DB / transferring data between servers?:

> Transfers of data are not allowed, except:
>
> To provide or improve your appropriate access or user-facing features
> that are visible and prominent in the requesting application's user
> interface and only with the user's consent;

3. Lastly, what if I use the data derived from that email is part of a larger dataset that is being collected internally. Would I be still prohibited from displaying e.g Recommendations based on their profile? Would Recommendation count as the Ad?

> All other transfers, uses, or sales of user data are prohibited,
> including:
>
> Transferring, selling, or **using** user data for serving ads, including retargeting, personalized or interest-based advertising.

Thanks

Comment: Ask `one` question per post. What is the problem you are trying to solve? When asking for clarification, word the post so that the response can be a fact and/or citation and not an opinion. Your post is quoting vendor policy that includes legal and/or contractual wording which makes your question off-topic. I would contact your lawyer or Google Support.